# Cannot open java dynamic web project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to open a new java dynamic web project and I run into this issue. Please help. I have installed java jdk version 1.8. My java version could be incompatible or what could cause this problem ?

```
    Failed while installing Java 1.8.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project cannot be cast to org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message, including the full stack trace. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.